# Chemical Kinetics - reversible reaction problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

This problem had a solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1248834/chemical-kinetics-using-laplace-transformation), but I do not know how to use Laplace transforms, so trying it using standard calculus tactics.

> For the reaction $\text{A} \rightleftharpoons \text{B}$, the rate of forward reaction is $k_1 = 0.02$ and rate of backward reaction is $k_2 = 0.03$. Find the time taken to achieve the half-life concentration of B (Time when the concentration of B is half that at equilibrium), given that the initial concentration of B is $0$.

Let the initial concentration of A be $A_0$. The equilibrium constant $K$ is given by $K = \frac{k_1}{k_2} = \frac23 = \frac BA$. Therefore, the final concentration of B would be $\frac23A_0$ and half of this is $\frac13A_0$

We have the differential equations 
$$\frac{dA}{dt} = -k_1A + k_2B \text {  and  } \frac{dB}{dt} = k_1A - k_2B$$ 
describing this system. We can see that  $dA = -dB$. Integrating both sides gives us $A-A_0 = B_0-B$ and substituting the values gives $A = A_0-B$. If we put this in the differential equation for $B$, we get

$$\frac{dB}{dt} = k_1(A_0-B) - k_2B \\ \frac{dB}{dt} + (k_1 + k_2)B = k_1A_0$$

This is a simple linear differential equation, whose solution is given by

$$B = \frac{k_1A_0}{k_1+k_2}\left( 1 - e^{-(k_1+k_2)t}\right)$$

If we substitute $B = \frac {A_0} {3}$, the time obtained is 
$$\frac13 = \frac25 \left( 1-e^{-0.05t}\right)\\ \implies t = 20\ln(6) \approx 35.84$$

Is this calculation correct? My textbook gives me a different answer for this problem.

Comment: You forgot a $B_0$ in $\frac{dB}{dt} = k_1(A_0-B) - k_2B \\ \frac{dB}{dt} + (k_1 + k_2)B = k_1A_0$

Comment: $B_0$ is 0, as stated in the question.

Comment: Ah, oops. Then it seems alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final concentration of $B$ would be $\dfrac23$ the final concentration of $A$.

The final concentration of $B$ would be $\dfrac2{\color{red}5}A_0$; the final concentration of $A$ would be $\dfrac35A_0$.

So the question is asking for the time $t$ when $B=\dfrac1{\color{red}5}A_0,$ not $\dfrac13A_0$.

$t=20\ln(\color{red}2)\approx13.86$.